# how to omit end tag enstead of self-closing element

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, xhtml

I want to change `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` to `<meta charset=UTF-8">` but on save its returning to self closing tag `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` .

Is there any option to not change it on save or any other solution?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You've tagged this [tag:xhtml] but the `/` is mandatory in XHTML. You also imply that your question is about how to configure **unspecified editor** so it doesn't format your code that way… but you haven't said what editor you are using or what formatting settings / plugins it is using.

Comment: sorry, I use vs code, I do have disabled autoclosing of HTML tags in settings.

Comment: it is an "bug" in the HTML 1.0 standard to allow unclosed tags, HTML5 has fixed this and does not allow these kind of tags only browsers still allow it to prevent a lot of websites to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code editor then follow the following steps to avoid adding a self-closing tag on the save of the file

**Go to File > Preference > Setting ( Ctrl +, ) Extension > HTML. And remove the tick from the "Auto Closing Tags".**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weGtH.png)

Afterward, If you want to use the "Auto Closing Tags" feature the same way you can enable the tick mark from the settings of VS code.