# code formatter settings (prettier) - how to stop autoclosing tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

my problem is that prettier in VS Code is automatically closing tags on save like that:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

to:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

To resolve problem i have to set:
ctrl + , -> type formatter -> **editor:default formatter set on none**.

But I still want to use prettier so how to stop auto closing tags in prettier ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to omit end tag enstead of self-closing element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75068928/how-to-omit-end-tag-enstead-of-self-closing-element)

Comment: why post the same question 2h later

Comment: i want to delete previous question because i made wrong question, unspecified question.

Comment: You have the ability to **EDIT** a question, this behavior will result in less people willing to respond even if they know the answer

Answer (score -3):

One way to disable auto-closing tags in Prettier is to set the `html-self-closing` option to false.

You can set this in the `settings.json` file in VS Code by adding the following line:

```
"prettier.htmlSelfClosing": false
```

You can also set this by adding the following configuration to your `.prettierrc` file:

```
{
  "htmlSelfClosing": false
}
```

Once this configuration is set, prettier will no longer automatically self-closing tags.
Alternatively you can add `// prettier-ignore` comment on the specific line where you want prettier to ignore the auto closing tags.

For this to work, you should have the latest version of Prettier installed and configured to work with VS Code.

Comment: 2023 doesn't work `[warn] Ignored unknown option { htmlSelfClosing: false }. `